# Play Framework 2 Bind form from request

Tags: forms, binding, playframework-2.0

I am new to Play2 (I've already developed a project using Play1) and I have problems with form binding from request.
The documentation about forms is really light.

Here is the code of my controller :

```
private final static Form<Estimation> estimationForm = form(Estimation.class);

/**
 * Get an estimation by form
 * @return
 */
public static Result estimation() {
    return ok(views.html.rate.estimation.render(
        estimationForm,
        City.findAll()
    ));
}

/**
 * Display estimation results
 * @return
 */
public static Result results() {
    if (request().method().equals("POST")) {
        Form<Estimation> form = estimationForm.bindFromRequest();
        if (form.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println(form.errorsAsJson().toString());
            return ok(views.html.rate.estimation.render(
                form
                City.findAll()
            ));
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(form.get());
            return ok(views.html.rate.results.render(

            ));
        }
    }
    else {
        return estimation();
    }
}
```

I display cities in a select as this :

```
<select id="city" name="city">      
    <option value="1">Paris, France</option>
    <option value="2">Lyon, France</option>
    <option value="3">Marseille, France</option>
    <option value="4">Barcelona, Spain</option>
    <option value="5">Berlin, Germany</option>
</select>
```

When I submit the form, I have the following error : 
{"city":["Invalid value"]}

So here is my question : The binder seems to work well with simple fields (for example a String property in my model), but what about @ManyToOne relationships ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the name of the select field as `name="city.id"`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I modified my code as you said but it is not better. When I print form.toString() this is what I have : 

Form(of=class models.analytic.Estimation, data={amount=125, city.id=1}, value=Some(null >> 125.0), errors={})

But when I try to save the object (form.get()) I have a validation error with NotNull constraint on the City field...

Do you have any idea ? Thank you again ;)

Comment: Sorry after more investigation, your answer fixes my problem. In fact, I tried to save directly the form.get() object but I have a field in the bean which is required and not in the form so its value was always null.

I fixed it by setting this field in the controller before saving the entity (if it can help someone else who has this problem ;))